# why lua bit.lshift(1, 40) is 256, not 1099511627776

Tags: math, lua, bit, luajit

I tried left-shift in python and lua, but get different result

lua

```
print(bit.lshift(1, 40))  --> 256
```

python

```
1 << 40   --> 1099511627776
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `bit.lshift` uses 32 bits (assuming this is the `bitop` library running under PUC Lua 5.1 / LuaJIT):

> It's desirable to define semantics that work the same across all platforms. This dictates that all operations are based on the common denominator of 32 bit integers. (https://bitop.luajit.org/semantics.html#range)

so it wraps around at `2^32` thus making the result `2^(40-32) = 2^8 = 256`.

whereas Python uses bigints:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 << 128
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
>>> 1 << 256
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

(these numbers well exceed 64-bit ints)

In Lua versions since 5.3, which have a 64 bit signed integer type, you'll get the same result:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 1 << 40
1099511627776
```

workaround in 5.1: Simply multiply by `2^40` instead of shifting:

```
$ lua5.1
> =2^40
1099511627776
```